# Value outputting as a number after a loop but when I add it to a list it adds 0?

Tags: r, loops

I initialize a list of size 100, and I want to go through a loop 100 times that executes an ifelse statement that, if true, adds a +1 to a score value, and then add that value to the list. Here is my code:

```
fwd_sizes = numeric(100)
for (i in 1:100) {
  ...
  new_coef <- coef(regfit.fwd,which.min(val.errors), complete=TRUE)
  # this outputs a list of up to 9 coefficients
  # below is the main part of the code I'm having issues with:
  size = 0
  for (item in new_coef) {
    size <- ifelse(abs(item) > 10**-3, size+1, size)
  }
  # if I print(size) after this loop, I get an actual number not 0
  fwd_sizes[i] = size
```

If I exit the loop and do

```
print(fwd_sizes)
```

it returns a list of (almost completely) 0's, which I know is incorrect based on print messages from inside the for loop. I also tried just using a regular if statement rather than ifelse, but had the same problem. What am I missing?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without being able to run the code. It looks fine. You could add both a `print(size)` and `print(fwd_sizes)` at every iteration to try to get a better sense of what's going on. Or you could somehow make the example reproducible so we can run it and see what's going on.

Comment: I would mention that `size = 0; for (item in new_coef) {size <- ifelse(abs(item) > 10**-3, size+1, size)}` looks like a long and inefficient way to write `size = sum(abs(item) > 10**-3)`.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, and sorry for the non-reproducible code, I felt like it was too complex to include the whole code. By printing the full list at every iteration, I figured out that I had used another for loop after the initial one, and used i as my iterator there as well, so when I was appending to fwd_sizes[i], it was taking the last i from the inner for loop. Silly...